# Problems synchronizing overleaf + Mendeley Desktop app

Tags: overleaf, mendeley

this problem just came from one moment to another. I use overleaf + Mendeley Desktop app to organize my references. As I Refresh my .bib file in overleaf there is no more content in it, it seems like the .bib file is empty. On Mendeley there are still all of my references, just not in the .bib file anymore..
I tried unlinking Mendeley and relink it again. Doesn't help.

Thankful for your help
Regards, Fabi

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. As far as I understand, Overleaf has a great support on their own, did you contact them yet about your problem?

Comment: Hi Fabi, Tom from Overleaf Support here. We've seen a few cases recently where Mendeley is requiring a re-linking and re-authorization. Sorry for the trouble.

Please try unlinking and re-linking your Mendeley account in the Overleaf's Account Settings at https://www.overleaf.com/user/settings -- that should do the trick.

If it doesn't help, can you please reach us at support@overleaf.com so that we can have a look at what's going on? Thanks!

Comment: thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it didn't help. I wrote an email to your support. Regards, Fabi